# Firebase: How To Access error object in iOS callback

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase Auth for iOS.

```
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
        if error == nil {
            //self.labelMessage.text = "You are successfully registered"
             self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }else{

        }

    })
```

This what i get when i do

```swift
print(error)
```

Error While Register Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17007 "The email address is already in use by another account." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is already in use by another account., error_name=ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE})

i want to access the error object to get the message programmatically.
something like

```swift
error.error_name ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: look at the errror in debug modus - not with print. then you see all elements

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode#firautherrorcodeemailalreadyinuse